# How to reset the 'lower triangle' of a 3 dimentional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I need to reset the 'lower triangle' of a 3 dimentional matrix.
This means, that if the original matrix is:

```
C(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 ;  2 4 6  ;  3  6  9]

C(:,:,2) = [2 4 6 ;  4 8 12 ;  6 12 18]

C(:,:,3) = [3 6 9 ;  6 12 18 ; 9 18 27]
```

Then the resulting matrix should be:

```
C(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 ;  2 4 6  ;  3  6  9]

C(:,:,2) = [0 0 0 ;  4 8 12 ;  6 12 18]

C(:,:,3) = [0 0 0 ;  0 0 0  ;  9 18 27]
```

Any idea how such a thing csn be done?
(My original 3 dim matrix is large)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in `triu` can't deal with this 3D array but you could do it in a simple loop.

```
for k = 2:size(C, 3)
    C(1:k-1,:,k) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a 2D mask, [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) its dimensions, and multiply with singleton expansion using [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = bsxfun(@times, C, permute((1:size(C,1)).'>=(1:size(C,2)), [1 3 2]));
```

Or, from version R2016b onwards, you can remove `bsxfun` thanks to [automatic singleton expansion](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html):

```
result = C .* permute((1:size(C,1)).'>=(1:size(C,2)), [1 3 2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a "square" 3-D matrix (i.e. NxNxN as you had it in your original post 3x3x3) you could also use reshaping and repmating:

Edit: since repmat is too slow, I swapped it for a bsxfun implementation.

```
[a,b,c] = size(C)
D = reshape(tril(ones(a)),[a,1,a]);
F = ones(1,size(E,1));
D = bsxfun(@times,D,F);
C(~D)=0;
```

I also did a quick comparison of the three proposed solutions. @LuisMendo's solution wouldn't work for me, there is a matrix dimension error in the >= comparison (sizes [1 N] and [N 1] are compared).

Between my and @Suever's solution, his is significantly faster:

```
Comparing the three methods with variable size Cs:
Suever's version (for loop):
Took 0.3529s to compute.
Took 0.0002s to compute size 3x3x3.
Took 0.0008s to compute size 10x10x10.
Took 0.0008s to compute size 50x50x50.
Took 0.0455s to compute size 250x250x250.
Took 0.3055s to compute size 500x500x500.
My version (reshape/repmat):
Took 0.9086s to compute.
Took 0.0522s to compute size 3x3x3.
Took 0.0042s to compute size 10x10x10.
Took 0.0017s to compute size 50x50x50.
Took 0.1060s to compute size 250x250x250.
Took 0.7445s to compute size 500x500x500.
```